# Access report prints slow

Tags: microsoft-access

I have an access report that comes up in a few seconds in the preview mode.  When I try to print it takes about 45 seconds to print.  Any ideas why this might be?  This is done in Access 2003.

Thanks,
Paul

Comment: You're unhappy with 45 seconds?

Comment: The fact that it comes up almost immediately in preview mode tells me there might be a problem.

Comment: Your printer is likely the bottleneck, since printers are by definition slower than RAM in a PC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How large is the report? What printer are you printing to? To determine whether the printer is at fault or something else, you could try installing PDF Creator (Windows printer driver that outputs to PDF files rather than a physical printer) and see if the report is "printed" faster to that. Once you've created a PDF of your report, try printing that PDF to your printer. Does that take 45 seconds?

Check the properties of the printer driver installed on the Dell. Is it outputting text as graphics? Some settings will create much larger spool files, which on a slower computer with a slower hard driver, will take a lot longer to print.

Comment: The code behind the report can take a different path based on whether the final destination will be the screen or printer. If the virtual printer produces the document quickly it is probably the report that is at fault.

Comment: One thing I have noticed is that the customer is on an older Dell.  It takes about 2 seconds on my newer computer going to the same printer.